# How to change gene/arrow direction/orientation in gggenes arrowplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, orientation, direction

Newbie here,

I have made an arrowplot with associated colours and managed to turn the gene direction for reverse strand, however, there is ONE gene that should be the other way, how do I do this?

This is the code I have:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gggenes)
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, y = molecule, fill = colour, forward = strand)) +
  geom_gene_arrow()+
  geom_gene_label(label = c("dahp", "dpgD", "dpgC", "dpgB", "dpgA", "gtfF", "riaD", "riaC", "riaB", "riaA", "hmo", "hmaS", "oxyD", "rpsE", "bhp", "pgat", "mtfB", "gtfE", "orf2", "gtfD", "mtfA", "gtfC", "gtfB", "gtfA", "oxyE", "oxyC", "oxyB", "oxyA", "mbtH", "rpsD (Dpg-TE)", "rpsC (Hpg-Hpg-βHt)", "rpsB (Dpg)", "rpsA (Hpg-βHt)", "tri", "pdh", "ajrR", "vanX", "vanA", "vanH"), align = "right") +
                    facet_wrap(~ molecule, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
                    theme(legend.position="top") + scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend", name = "Gene Function", labels = c("Methyltransferase", "Regulator", "Resistance", "β-hydroxytyrosine Synthesis Proteins", "Peptide Synthetase", "Oxygenase", "Dihydroxyphenylglycine Synthesis Proteins", "Hydroxyphenylglycine Synthesis Proteins", "Prephenate Dehydrogenase", "mbtH-like Protein", "ABC Transporter", "DAHP Synthase", "Aminotransferase", "Ristosamine Synthesis", "Glycosyltransferase", "Deacylase (inactive)"))
```

![output][1]

```
 molecule start   end  strand   gene  orientation  colour
 KJ364518.1  2314  3345 reverse vanH 1  #f15854
 KJ364518.1  3347  4387 reverse vanA 1  #f15854
 KJ364518.1  4384  4992 reverse vanX 1  #f15854
 KJ364518.1  6334  7125 reverse ajrR 1  #faa43a
 KJ364518.1  7246  8097 reverse pdh  1  #5da5da
 KJ364518.1  8410 10272 reverse tri  1  #b276b2
```

Thanks so much everyone!
Lucy

Comment: Need example data. Why not modify examples from that package?

Comment: Added some example data! :)

Comment: I already took my own advice. What seemed to be the obvious first attempt working without complaint by the code.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to reverse the arrow of the first genome in the `example_genes` dataset used in the help page for `geom_gene_arrows`, I got immediate success by simply swapping the values of `start` and `end`:

```
tem <- example_genes$start[1]; example_genes$start[1] <- example_genes$end[1]; example_genes$end[1] <-tem

ggplot2::ggplot(example_genes, ggplot2::aes(xmin = start, xmax = end,
                                        y = molecule, fill = gene)) +
   geom_gene_arrow() +
   ggplot2::facet_wrap(~ molecule, scales = "free")
```

[image]

You need to look in the Genome5 facet since that happens to be the first "molecule" value:

```
str(example_genes)
#--------------
'data.frame':   72 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ molecule   : chr  "Genome5" "Genome5" "Genome5" "Genome5" ...
 $ gene       : chr  "genA" "genB" "genC" "genD" ...
 $ start      : num  407035 407035 407927 408387 408751 ...
 $ end        : num  405113 407916 408394 408737 409830 ...
 $ strand     : chr  "forward" "forward" "forward" "reverse" ...
 $ orientation: num  -1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 ...
```